# js - how to import functions from the @turf/meta module

Tags: javascript, npm, import, turfjs

I am trying to import a function named `coordEach` from the npm module `@turf/meta`. I tried using import and desturctoring the function, but I am getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

my code:

```
import { coordEach } from "@turf/meta";

export const morphGeoJSON = (feature, bbox, width, height) => {
  coordEach(
    feature,
    (
      currentCoords,
      coordIndex,
      featureIndex,
      multiFeatureIndex,
      geometryIndex
    ) => {
      debugger;
    }
  );

  return feature;
};
```

as far as I can tell I am importing everything from the [package](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-meta/index.mjs) correctly. The npm install is also ok.

What am I missing?

I also tried

```
import turfMeta from "@turf/meta"

turfMeta.coordEach(feature, () => {debugger})
```

The error there is:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError):
>   __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__turf_meta___default.a.coordEach is not a function

Comment: Did you install it like `npm install @turf/meta`

Comment: yeah, also tried nuking `node_modules` and reinstalling, but it does not help

Comment: Can you try `import * as meta from '@turf/meta';`

Comment: getting the same result as with `import turfMeta from "@turf/meta"` p default.a.coordEach is not a function

Comment: I tryed with the cdn version and it's working https://jsfiddle.net/pfc92u2m/1/

Comment: If I see this correctly you are importing the whole turf library from the cdn instead of only the meta package?

Comment: That's correct...if anything fails you can use it that way